# How do I sort, get rid of numbers and organize?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I were to ask someone to enter value:

```
value = input("List numbers: ")
```

and I wanted to organize it:

User Input = 1, 2, 3, 2

and get a print() of 1, 2, 3 as a result- getting rid of extra numbers
How would I go about doing that?
and also
How would I organize them? 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 for an example 2 1 4 3 5 and get a print() of 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: @Stephan, I am new to programming so using your guide helped me visualize what I needed to do and seeing your example answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a step by step guide to

- Accepting input
- Splitting into a list
- Converting elements to integers
- Removing duplicates
- Sorting the list

---

```
input = raw_input("Please enter your numbers separated by commas: ")
inputList = input.split(',')              # creates a list from comma delimeters
intList = [int(i) for i in inputList]     # converts to int list
uniqueList = set(intList)                 # removes duplicates
sortedList = sorted(uniqueList)           # converts to ints and sorts
```

This code requires the user to use commas to separate values.  This can be changed.

To do the same thing with strings try this

```
input = raw_input("Please enter your words separated by commas: ")
inputList = input.split(',')              # creates a list from comma delimeters
uniqueList = set(inputList)               # removes duplicates
sortedList = sorted(uniqueList)           # converts to ints and sorts
```

Comment: You forgot a step; your inputs are still strings.

Comment: After fixing the typos try it with: `"2 100 4 3 5"`

Comment: You think the OP wants ASCII-lexicographic order? That seems unlikely.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to sort it correctly without converting to an integer. Try `sorted(['5', '10'])`.

Comment: Would it be possible to use this same code to sort words also?

Comment: for an example: baby, chocolate, apple to apple, baby, chocolate

Comment: yes, if you remove the `int` cast @Stevenson (the third line)

Comment: You could also just remove the whole LC instead of making up a copy of the list.

Comment: Could you please show me an example? when I try do the same thing choosing 3 words separated by commas I get Type Error: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @Stevenson sure, i'll post a string example in my answer in a few minutes, check back soon

Comment: @Stevenson the example is up

Comment: Okay, now I understand.. that clarifies my issue

Answer (score 5):

It seems you're looking for a list of sorted unique numbers. You can use `sorted(set(map(int, value.split(",")))` to get that. See the Demo -

```
>>> value = raw_input("List numbers: ")
List numbers: 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 1
>>> sorted(set(map(int, value.split(','))))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

1. `value.split(',')` splits the input list on `','`, thus returning a list of strings.
2. `map(int, ...)` converts each entry in the above list to an integer.
3. `set(...)` makes a set out of the above list, thus eliminating any duplicates.
4. `sorted(...)` sorts the set and produces a list.

You could then use `join(...)` method to convert it back into a string. If for example you wanted to seperate them with a `', '`, you could do

```
>>> ", ".join(map(str, sorted(set(map(int, value.split(',')))))) # Or use an equivalent List Comprehension.
'1, 2, 3, 4, 5'
```

Comment: To handle arbitrary amounts of whitespace, you might instead `split` on `','` and `strip` the results.

Comment: No need to strip the whitespaces in that case, `int(...)` would take care of it. :)

Comment: Oh, hey, it does. Nice.